# Android File Picker

Tags: android, file-io, filepicker

Is there a good solution for picking a file in an android application? I need the user to be able to browse their SD card for a file they would like to load. However, it cannot use an outside application (like andExplorer or OI File Manager). It must stay contained inside my application and not require users to install other applications.

Using Intent.GET_CONTENT will not work because the files are of a custom type.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ironically I ended up integrating the OI File Manager into my application myself, since the source had been released via svn.

If there's a better way for those looking for the answer to the same question feel free to speak up.

Comment: Hi, there is a library here: http://code.google.com/p/android-filechooser/

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still searching for answers, here is a good example with code to create a file chooser/picker [simple file chooser](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190013-creating-simple-file-chooser/)

Comment: Or yoe can use this one:  https://github.com/Angads25/android-filepicker

Answer (score 3):

You can also use my library, which does exactly what you described: [aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser)